# How to extract a token between specific characters in a string

Tags: regex

I have a string like;

```
Something{this i want1}.{this i want2}oyherthings[{this also i want1}.{this also i want2}]morethings
```

I want the output like below.

```
this i want1
this i want2
this also i want
```

I can do using substring function of java. But i was wondering if it can be done using regex.
I have tried some regex combinations but unable to make it work.
Some regex i tried.

```
Pattern matchString = Pattern.compile("{(.*?}");
Matcher matcher = "
Something{this i want1}.{this i want2}oyherthings[{this also i want}]morethings";
```

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your curly braces are always balanced, you could use the following.

```
\\{([^}]*)}
```

And then refer to group(1) to retrieve the match result.

[**Explanation**](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%7B%28%5B%5E%7D%5D*%29%7D&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode) | [<kbd>Code Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/2mIagv)

Comment: The explanation was pretty useful +1 for explanation :)

Comment: What if I wanted the output as below for input       "Something{this i want1}.{this i want2}otherthings[{this also i want1}.{this also I want2}]morethings"                        {this i want1}                                              {this i want2}                                             [{this also i want1}{this also i want2}]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
String s = "Something{this i want1}.{this i want2}oyherthings[{this also i want}]morethings";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{)[^{}]*(?=\\})");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

**Output:**

```
this i want1
this i want2
this also i want
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Can you please also give a bit of insight how it works. What if I wanted the output as below for input                                               Something{this i want1}.{this i want2}otherthings[{this also i want1}.{this also I want2}]morethings"                       {this i want1}
{this i want2}
[{this also i want1}{this also i want2}]

Comment: use this regex `\\{[^{}]*\\}` and then print group index 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
{([^}]*)}
```

Try this.Grab the matches.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/34

Comment: Thanks for this link , its quite useful for testing the regex with input string. Although the expression suggested with you didn't work.